# Joined inheritance strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I m using inheritance type equal to joined in my spring project .I had a class called Identifier which had 4 types called ( direct , indirect , urgent , info ) . While inserting one identifier with one type like direct or else it is OK .But i want to insert multiple types with the same identifier Id which it is not permitted because the id is a primary key can not be duplicated . How can I achieve this propose ???

Maybe another inheritance strategy could achieve the requested goal.

```
@Table(name = "identifier")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE_IDEN", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 2)
```

Actually , I'm blocked if there is anyway to do that .

Comment: Can you provide the full class including the mapping? Maybe a composite primary key is what you need

Comment: what do you mean by full class ? I think the problem is clear !!!

Comment: Well, there is a difference between what you think and what we see. Provide the whole mapping

Answer (score 0):

You modeled your problem with an inheritance solution. You have one super class with four children. Ask yourself: is possible for any subclass in **java**  to be of more than one type at the same time? Considering what is written in the question, it is what you're trying to do, and it's impossible.

If you want your class to hold more than one set of characteristics, you'll have to **reconsider the way you're modeling your problem.**

If you need an "Identifier" to hold any number of "types", maybe you should use composition, so instead of an "Identifier" **being** a "direct" or "indirect", it will **contain** a "direct" **and/or** "indirect".

This is only a suggestion, there are multiple solutions and I am not aware of all your needs, but keep in mind that your current modeling won't allow you to have the behavior you described.

Comment: What i want to do is to insert for exmaple a group of any type of identifier such direct  but with the same id referenced to the parent class which is identifier . What i find now it not possible is this strategy because the chid class had the same id of the parent class when adding new element which let me to add only one row not multiple rows .

Comment: Any inheritance strategy available won't do what you are saying. Again, what looks like what you are after is a composition (A has many of B), not inheritance.